# Error running topeka-instantapp: URL not defined in the manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-instant-apps

I am working on instant app and was implementing the google code lab example. 
Everything is going ok but in the last I got this error:

> Error running topeka-instantapp: URL
>   "https://topeka.samples.androidinstantapps.com/signin" not defined in the manifest

What to do for this ?

Comment: I've noticed that you have create a issue ticket in their github. You can include that link for the sake of other readers.

Comment: please post your android manifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved:** Url which are added through App Link Assistant to the manifest must contains "**`https`**". In my case there is two with "**`https`**" and two with "**`http`**".

Comment: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-instant-apps/#5
This error typically comes from misconfiguring the app links.

Comment: Yes, I implemented as they mention the links, so there is misconfiguring.